# Mismatch between host (RHEL8) and container (UBI8) subscriptions

Tags: rhel, podman

According to [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/building_running_and_managing_containers/index#assembly_working-with-containers_building-running-and-managing-containers) and basically any tutorial on the Internet, my podman containers should take advantage of it's host's subscriptions.

But in my case it does not...

On my host, I have  :

```
# yum repolist enabled
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
repo id                                         repo name
dirsrv-11-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms                Red Hat Directory Server 11 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)   <= I enabled this repo on the host, thanks to my subscription
rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms                Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms                   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)
```

But, inside a podman container :

```
# yum repolist enabled
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity    <= this does not look good....
Subscription Manager is operating in container mode.
repo id                                    repo name
ubi-8-appstream                            Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStream
ubi-8-baseos                               Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS
ubi-8-codeready-builder                    Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder
 <= My repo is missing !
```

In the container, I do have access to the required files :

```
# ls -la /run/secrets/
total 260
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root    120 Aug 29 16:19 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   4096 Aug 29 16:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     72 Aug 23 13:08 etc-pki-entitlement
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 257134 Aug 26 12:40 redhat.repo
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root    104 Aug 23 09:00 rhsm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      0 Aug 29 16:19 system-fips
```

Any idea what is going on here ?

Thanks for your help !

G.B.

Edit : some information about my system :

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.6 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.6"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6"

# podman -v
podman version 4.1.1

# buildah -v
buildah version 1.26.2 (image-spec 1.0.2-dev, runtime-spec 1.0.2-dev)

#  yum --version
4.4.2
  Installed: rpm-0:4.14.3-23.el8.x86_64 at Thu Aug 25 09:26:36 2022
  Built    : Red Hat, Inc. <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> at Tue Apr  5 18:38:09 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you still need help but I just came across a similar issue. In my case, I'm using a RHEL 8.7 VM in VirtualBox. I got almost the exact same issue. For me it's because I have docker installed on my host Windows machine. It has some virtualization features that apparently mess with VirtualBox. To fix this, I navigated to Apps & features > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off. Disable and Hypervisor or virtual machine features you see (specifically for me it was Virtual Machine Platform). After that I rebooted my system and started the VM again and everything worked. I was still getting the error message but my scripts can run now and access all the repositories I needed. Note that doing this will break Docker on your host. You will have to uninstall and reinstall to fix it. I hope this helps.